# Equations,inequalities and absolute values.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

I really am confused when I am supposed to change the $<$ and $>$ symbol.

For example this unsolved question  in my reference book:

> solve $\displaystyle \frac{x+1}{x-1}>0$

One example shows that the answer is $x>1$ and $x>-1$  ... while my other reference book the example shows that the answer is  $x>1$ and $x<-1$

Is it $x<-1$ or $x>-1$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is $x<-1$ or $x>1$. You should decide for what values $x+1$ and $x-1$ have the same sign, and this happens for $x<-1$ or for $x>1$.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly $x \neq 1$ (denominator). For the fraction to be negative, either numerator is positive AND denominator is negative OR numerator is negative AND denominator is positive. Can you handle the rest?

EDIT Keep in mind though that there exist 'impossible' solution intervals, i.e. such that $ x < a$ AND $x>b$ where $a<b$.